# Как вставить текст или переменную в форму программой php?

Tags: php, html

Как вставить текст или переменную в форму программой php? Объясните кто знает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если доскональна понимать ваш вопрос, то сделать нужно так :

```
<?php
$vn1 = 'Текст213123123';
echo '<input type="text" name="ololo" value="'.$vn1.'"/>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP - серверный язык. Формы создаются браузером, и взаимодействовать они не могут.

Чтобы добавить поле ввода - впишите

```
<input type="text" name="var_name" value="var_value" />
```

, в php значение будет доступно из **$_GET['var_name']**.Или если у формы указан method="post", то из **$_POST['var_name']**.